# How can I re-enable ctrl-s inside Emacs inside GNU screen?

Tags: emacs, gnu-screen

When editing code inside a GNU screen session (which I do a lot) using Emacs, I sometimes get into a state where everything still works (e.g. editing and scrolling works normally), except for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> which is absolutely catastrophic in emacs. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> seems to be silently ignored. As if I never pressed it. Other Ctrl combinations seem to work fine (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>).

I tried this to recover:

- Reset terminal from within the shell.
- Reset terminal in GNU screen.
- Restart emacs.

None of this helped.

What happened?

How can I bring <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> back to life?

Comment: By `Ctrl-S`, we just mean `Ctrl-s`, your normal search command in Emacs.

Comment: Yes. I clarified that now, using lower case letters. This state becomes immediately apparent to me since I save files a lot (`Ctrl-x Ctrl-s`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What happened?

You most likely pressed Ctrl-a and then F by accident. This toggles flow control handling in GNU screen. When flow control handling is enabled in GNU screen Ctrl-s and Ctrl-q (Xon and Xoff) are no longer passed to the inner application.

> How can I bring Ctrl-s back to life?

To disable flow control handling in GNU screen (the default) press Ctrl-a and then F again. It should then show `-flow` in the status line. Ctrl-s and Ctrl-q are now working again in emacs as expected.

Comment: Of course, `Ctrl-a` is whatever your default control key is in screen (because I already use `Ctrl-a` in Emacs, I personally changed my default control key to `Ctrl-z`).

Comment: @shaneb Yes! And I use `Ctrl-t`. `Ctrl-a` is such a poor choice. :-) I just used `Ctrl-a` here as meta-syntactic variable for "whatever your screen control key is".